# can java inputstream read files that are being updated in memory?

Tags: java

Rather reading the file from harddisk.

Comment: lets say we have a excel file that is being updated constantly.  Without having to save that excel file, can we read its updated data?

Answer (score 2):

> lets say we have a excel file that is being updated constantly. Without having to save that excel file, can we read its updated data? – vamsi

No. Its in-memory data representation is unlikely to be the same as its representation as a saved file. Nor will java allow you address arbitrary memory.

Answer (score 1):

Memory mapped IO, here's a tutorial:

http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/1548681/Introduction-to-Memory-Mapped-IO-in-Java.htm

Your comment suggested memory outside of the Java Virtual Machine: this is always prohibited. This is not just by Java, but prohibited by any OS (unless you use platform-dependent hacks, but I don't know anything about these).